# Shiny Leaflet map renders twice on switching input

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-leaflet

I'm trying to produce a Shiny app with Leaflet that renders a choropleth map based on different input criteria. The map displays incidents of different types (`input$type`) and backgrounds (`input$background`). When additional types or backgrounds are specified, polygons are filled with updated incident data. It is working correctly with one snag. When I switch the date input from date range (`input$dateInput`)  to presidential period (`input$president`), the choropleth for presidential period renders once, displaying polygons with no data, and then again with the polygons filled with the correct data for the pre-selected period ("President1"). How do I avoid the map rendering twice like this when the Presidency tab is pressed?

Question also listed [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-leaflet-map-renders-twice-on-switching-input/7863) on RStudio Community.

The raw data and shapefile used can be accessed here: https://github.com/cjbarrie/shiny_egy.

Working example:

Name of raw data: `wikiraw`

Name of shapefile: `shapefile`

Global:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(rmapshaper)
library(sp)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

wikiraw <-read.csv("~/wikisample_SO.csv")
shapefile <- readOGR("~/EGY_adm2.shp")
shapefile<-spTransform(shapefile, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
## Simplify shapefile to speed up rendering
shapefile <- ms_simplify(shapefile, keep = 0.01, keep_shapes = TRUE)
wikbounds<-bbox(shapefile)
wikiraw$incident_date <- as.Date(wikiraw$incident_date,
                                 format = "%m/%d/%Y")
wikiraw$presidency <- rep(NA, nrow(wikiraw))
wikiraw$incident_date1 <- as.numeric(wikiraw$incident_date)
wikiraw$event <- rep(1,nrow(wikiraw))
## Generate presidency categorical var.
wikiraw$presidency <- cut(wikiraw$incident_date1, 
                          breaks = c(-Inf, 15016, 15521, 15889, 16229, Inf), 
                          labels = c("President1", "President2", "President3", "President4", "President5"), 
                          right = FALSE)
```

Snippet of data.frame `wikiraw`:

```
  ID_2 incident_date incident_background incident_type presidency event
1  168    2013-11-26            Cultural         Group President4     1
2  133    2013-11-29            Cultural         Group President4     1
3  137    2014-01-25            Cultural         Group President4     1
4  168    2011-01-28            Cultural    Collective President1     1
5  168    2016-04-25            Cultural         Group President5     1
6  163    2015-02-08           Political    Individual President5     1
```

UI:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
                    dashboardHeader(title = "Map tool"),
                    dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem("Map", tabName = "map"),
                                                 selectInput("input_type", "Date input type",
                                                             c("Date", "Presidency")),
                                                 uiOutput("dateSelect"),
                                                 uiOutput("typeSelect"),
                                                 uiOutput("backgroundSelect"),
                                                 uiOutput("presidentSelect"))),
                    dashboardBody(tabItems(
                      tabItem(tabName = "map",
                              leafletOutput("mymap", height=500)))))
```

Server:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$dateSelect <- renderUI({
    switch(input$input_type,
           "Date" = dateRangeInput("dateInput", "Dates:",
                                   min=min(wikiraw$incident_date), max = max(wikiraw$incident_date),
                                   start = min(wikiraw$incident_date), end = max(wikiraw$incident_date)),
           "Presidency" = checkboxGroupInput("president", "Presidency", 
                                             choices = levels(wikiraw$presidency),
                                             selected = "President1"))
  })

  output$typeSelect <- renderUI({
    selectInput("type", "Incident type", 
                choices = unique(wikiraw$incident_type), multiple = TRUE, 
                selected = wikiraw$incident_type[1])})

  output$backgroundSelect <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput("background", "Incident background", 
                       choices = unique(wikiraw$incident_background),
                       selected = wikiraw$incident_background[1])})


  selected <- reactive({
    wikiagg <- wikiraw %>% group_by(ID_2, incident_date, incident_type, incident_background, presidency) %>%
      summarize(sum_event = sum(event))
    if(input$input_type=="Date"){wikiagg <- filter(wikiagg,
                                                   incident_date >= min(input$dateInput),
                                                   incident_date <= max(input$dateInput),
                                                   incident_type%in%input$type,
                                                   incident_background%in%input$background)}
    if(input$input_type=="Presidency"){wikiagg <- filter(wikiagg,
                                                         incident_type%in%input$type,
                                                         incident_background%in%input$background,
                                                         presidency%in%input$president)}

    wikiagg <- wikiagg %>% group_by(ID_2) %>%
      summarize(sum_event = sum(sum_event))
    wikiagg
  })

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({

    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      setView(mean(wikbounds[1,]),
              mean(wikbounds[2,]),
              zoom=6
      )
  })

  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$dateInput)){
      shapefile@data <- left_join(shapefile@data, selected(), by="ID_2")

      ##Define palette across range of data
      wikiaggpal <- wikiraw %>% group_by(ID_2) %>%
        summarize(sum_event = sum(event))
      pal <- colorBin("YlOrRd", wikiaggpal$sum_event, bins=5, na.color = "#bdbdbd")


      leafletProxy("mymap", data = shapefile) %>%
        addTiles() %>% 
        clearShapes() %>% 
        addPolygons(data = shapefile, fillColor = ~pal(sum_event), fillOpacity = 0.7, 
                    color = "white", weight = 2)
    }})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Gif of issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S81SI.jpg

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example. Otherwise, we can't run your code.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this. I have edited original post, adding link to github repo containing raw data and shapefile used.

Comment: I can't load you shapefile...I think we also need the other files with the .shp file

Comment: Github repo updated with supplementary shapefiles. Thanks again!

Comment: That's odd--I don't get any such error. Also I just checked and ID_2 is integer class in both the shapefile and wikiraw.

My sessionInfo if helpful:

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.3

Comment: yah, mines were different....but you get a lot of NA when you merge them together

Comment: Yep--I'm just generating these with a v small subset of data given to me by those who commissioned this before the full dataset is sent to me. Most will be NA

Comment: Just checking @MLavoie that you managed to reproduce the issue I specify above? Also do let me know anyone else looking at this if more guidance needed on exact issue.

Comment: I am not sure If I really see what you mean. The differences between some of the selection (polygon colors) are almost the same making it hard to see the problem.

Comment: Hey @MLavoie, thanks for your reply. I've posted an Imgur link to the issue at the bottom of the original post. When I click on the "Presidency" tab, the map initially renders twice as you'll see

Comment: remove `clearShapes() %>% ` and tell me if this is better.

Comment: That doesn't help, unfortunately. Just means that polygons don't clear from the previous rendering when you switch between Date and Presidency

Comment: Maybe remove the `addTiles()` from the `leafletProxy`.

Comment: @cjb, I also got a class-error on the join. ID_2 is integer and factor. I would include that in your example: `shapefile@data$ID_2 <- as.numeric(shapefile@data$ID_2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you change the `reactive` to a `reactiveValue` and assign the data in an `observe`? I don't know if it is working correctly as I dont know which shapes & colors to expect, but I am not seeing that double rendering anymore.

(*Data & Preparation from question is used*)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(rmapshaper)
library(sp)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Map tool"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem("Map", tabName = "map"),
                               selectInput("input_type", "Date input type",
                                           c("Date", "Presidency")),
                               uiOutput("dateSelect"),
                               uiOutput("typeSelect"),
                               uiOutput("backgroundSelect"),
                               uiOutput("presidentSelect"))),
  dashboardBody(tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "map",
            leafletOutput("mymap", height=500)))))



server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$dateSelect <- renderUI({
    switch(input$input_type,
           "Date" = dateRangeInput("dateInput", "Dates:",
                                   min=min(wikiraw$incident_date), max = max(wikiraw$incident_date),
                                   start = min(wikiraw$incident_date), end = max(wikiraw$incident_date)),
           "Presidency" = checkboxGroupInput("president", "Presidency", 
                                             choices = levels(wikiraw$presidency),
                                             selected = "President1"))
  })

  output$typeSelect <- renderUI({
    selectInput("type", "Incident type", 
                choices = unique(wikiraw$incident_type), multiple = TRUE, 
                selected = wikiraw$incident_type[1])})

  output$backgroundSelect <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput("background", "Incident background", 
                       choices = unique(wikiraw$incident_background),
                       selected = wikiraw$incident_background[1])})

  sel_reactval = reactiveValues(s = NULL)

  # selected <- reactive({
  observe({
    wikiagg <- wikiraw %>% group_by(ID_2, incident_date, incident_type, incident_background, presidency) %>%
      summarize(sum_event = sum(event))

    if(input$input_type=="Date"){wikiagg <- filter(wikiagg,
                                                   incident_date >= min(input$dateInput),
                                                   incident_date <= max(input$dateInput),
                                                   incident_type%in%input$type,
                                                   incident_background%in%input$background)}
    if(input$input_type=="Presidency"){wikiagg <- filter(wikiagg,
                                                         incident_type%in%input$type,
                                                         incident_background%in%input$background,
                                                         presidency%in%input$president)}

    wikiagg <- wikiagg %>% group_by(ID_2) %>%
      summarize(sum_event = sum(sum_event))

    sel_reactval$s = wikiagg
    # wikiagg
  })

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({

    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      setView(mean(wikbounds[1,]),
              mean(wikbounds[2,]),
              zoom=6
      )
  })

  observe({

    req(!is.null(input$dateInput))
    req(nrow(as.data.frame(sel_reactval$s))!=0)

    # if(!is.null(input$dateInput)){
      # shapefile@data <- left_join(shapefile@data, selected(), by="ID_2")
      shapefile@data <- left_join(shapefile@data, sel_reactval$s, by="ID_2")

      ##Define palette across range of data
      wikiaggpal <- wikiraw %>% group_by(ID_2) %>%
        summarize(sum_event = sum(event))
      pal <- colorBin("YlOrRd", wikiaggpal$sum_event, bins=5, na.color = "#bdbdbd")


      leafletProxy("mymap") %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        clearShapes() %>%
        addPolygons(data = shapefile, fillColor = ~pal(sum_event), fillOpacity = 1, 
                    color = "white", weight = 2)
    # }
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I think this has fixed it! I'll need to play around with it a bit more to make sure but it seems to be rendering correctly now. Thanks so much (and apologies for only just getting round to looking at this). I shall be raising a glass to you this evening!